# Set width of the concatenated column in Oracle SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, width

I'm trying to set width of the concatenated column in Oracle but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

I have something like this (simplified):

```
SELECT t.first_name || ' ' || t.family_name "Trainer name"
FROM trainer t
```

The output looks as follows:

```
Trainer name                       
------------------------------------
Bill Gates                        
Steve Jobs                           
Isaac Asimov
```

And I'm trying to limit the column width to, let's say, 18 characters. I was trying to use COLUMN

```
COLUMN t.first_name || ' ' || t.family_name FORMAT A18
```

But that's not working. The documentation says: "If you use an expression in a COLUMN command, you must enter expr exactly as it appears in the SELECT command". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option, cast the output to a char(18):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69410/1

```
SELECT 
    cast(t.first_name || ' ' || t.family_name as char(18))   as "Trainer name"
FROM trainer t
```

Answer (score 1):

You've aliased the column, so you have to use the alias in the `column` command:

```
COLUMN "Trainer name" FORMAT A18

SELECT t.first_name || ' ' || t.family_name "Trainer name"
FROM trainer t;

Trainer name
------------------
Bill Gates
Steve Jobs
Isaac Asimov
```

You might find it cleaner to user a simpler alias and a column heading, separating - somewhat - function from display:

```
CLEAR COLUMNS
COLUMN trainer_name FORMAT A18 HEADING "Trainer name"

SELECT t.first_name || ' ' || t.family_name AS trainer_name
FROM trainer t;

Trainer name
------------------
Bill Gates
Steve Jobs
Isaac Asimov
```

Either way, if the concatenated value exceeds 18 characters, the value will wrap onto a second line. To avoid that you'd have to `substr` the value, which might not be desirable either.

Comment: @samuelg0rd0n - you have to match the case exactly using double-quoted identifiers, to maybe you did `COLUMN "trainer name"` or something. One of the reasons to avoid them *8-)